# jQuery on click replace image IE9 Bug

Tags: jquery, onclick, internet-explorer-9

in IE9 only i have small images and when the user clicks this it shows the small image in the above div that is a larger size so you can see the full image - it works in all browsers apart from IE9 and i dont know what else i can do to sort this out - is it a caching issue? css issue? script issue?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // image swap on the events template
    var $MainLargeImage = $('.control.Event .RightSide .Images .LargeImage');
    var $ThumbnailImages = $('.control.Event .RightSide .Images .smallImages img.SmallImage');

    $ThumbnailImages.click(function () {
        $MainLargeImage.attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
</script>
```

You can see the problem here: http://team-spirit.co.uk/events/library/A-Taste-Of-Vegas.aspx

Comment: Check the console in IE9 for errors. I see nothing obvious in the code which would not work, my guess would be this is a symptom of another error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it says this 'SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'superfish'' but on the localhost in IE9 it does not bring it up

Comment: Have you uploaded the superfish script to the server?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes and i got rid of the error it works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt - even restarted the website in IIS - It is using the same template so if there was an issue one page using the same template it should be replicated throughout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this, and let me know what the console.log's generate?

```
$ThumbnailImages.on('click',function () {

    console.log(this);
    var src=$(this).prop('src');
    console.log(src);
    console.log($MainLargeImage.prop('src'));
    $MainLargeImage.prop('src', src);
    console.log($MainLargeImage.prop('src'));

});
```

Comment: It brings back Line: 3
Error: '$ThumbnailImages' is undefined

Comment: it works for all of them but then for some strange reason on click some of the images dont get replaced with the big image and in the console log nothing is being shown - really am lost now with what it can be.

Comment: the selector on this line needs to be fixed: `var $ThumbnailImages = $('.control.Event .RightSide .Images .smallImages img.SmallImage');`

Comment: if `$ThumbnailImages` is undefined then this string `'.control.Event .RightSide .Images .smallImages img.SmallImage'` is wrong. Without seeing the HTML code I couldnt tell you what the correct selector would be. But making the selector simpler (like `img.SmallImage` for example) might help. Selectors are case sensitive - so double check that as well.

Comment: too many selectors limiting it and tweaking it a little fixed the issue - if it mucks around in IE9 i'll ignore it - losing the will to live - IE should never exist anymore! Nightmare - thank you for your time :)

Comment: no probs. I shouldnt, but I cant help myself from agreeing with you on IE! It is a nightmare! :)

Comment: you would expect ie7 to be a pain but its ie9 in this case - right thanks for pointing part of the problem out - hugely appreciated :)